# python how to use dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to read data from some files and save those into dictionary
The file that I am reading looks like below

```
file_1.txt
line 1: Given Problem1, Incorrect Answer, Correct Answer, Rule
line 2:  ___blank___ , Incorrect_Answer
line 3:  ___blank___ , Incorrect_Answer
line 4: Given Problem2, Incorrect Answer, Correct Answer, Rule
line 5:  ___blank___ , Incorrect_Answer
line 6:  ___blank___ , Incorrect_Answer
```

So there are one Question, Correct Answer, and Rule but several Incorrect_Answer

The form of dictionary that I want to get looks like below
{Question, Incorrect_Answer[...(array maybe?)], Correct_Answer, Rule }

I got so far this.

```
for line in open(thatfile.txt,'r').readlines()[2:]: # scan through the file, but skip the first two lines that contain metadata (data headers)
if line[0].startswith('Question '):
    continue:
elif line starts with ' ' #there will be only incorrect_answer in this line
    input line[1] to Incorrect_Answer array
else 
    input line[0] to Question
    input line[1] to Incorrect_Answer array
    input line[2] to Correct_Answer
    input line[3] to Rule $
```

Comment: What problem(s) are you having with this code?  Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: Is this *exactly* what the file looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to start with a main output result container and a question placeholder:

```
>>> result = {}
>>> question = None
```

Then you do your normal processing of each line while watching for question changes, appending incorrect responses:

```
>>> for line in txtfile:
...   pieces = line.split(',')
...   if pieces[0] not in (question, ' ___blank___ '):
...     question = pieces[0]
...     result[question] = {'Incorrect': [pieces[1]],
...                         'Correct': pieces[2],
...                         'Rule': pieces[3]}
...   elif pieces[0].startswith(' '):
...     result[question]['Incorrect'].append(pieces[1])
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> pprint(result)
{'Given Problem1': {'Correct': ' Correct Answer',
                    'Incorrect': [' Incorrect Answer',
                                  ' Incorrect_Answer',
                                  ' Incorrect_Answer'],
                    'Rule': ' Rule'},
 'Given Problem2': {'Correct': ' Correct Answer',
                    'Incorrect': [' Incorrect Answer',
                                  ' Incorrect_Answer',
                                  ' Incorrect_Answer'],
                    'Rule': ' Rule'}}
```

Comment: what does not in (question, ' blank' ) mean?

Comment: `not in (question, ' ___blank___ ')` is a way to determine when the question changes.  Because you don't get a question on blank lines, you're comparing the current question (or empty entry) to the last encountered question.  The condition only fires when you see a new question you've never seen (or the first question, when the placeholder is `None`).

Comment: thank you for quick reply! 
I got the concept and now know why there is not in (question), but still a bit confused about '___blank___' part. so does it check whether pieces[0] got ___blank___ or not? if so, it will skip the condition right?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that - as you are writing above - the question and answers are separated by commas.

```
alldata = []
# scan through the file, but skip the first two lines 
# that contain metadata (data headers)
for line in open(thatfile.txt,'r').readlines()[2:]:
    lineparts = line.split(',') # or how else can one separate the parts?
    if len(lineparts) == 4:
        thisset = {'Question': lineparts[0], 
                   'Incorrect': [lineparts[1]], 
                   'Correct': lineparts[2],
                   'Rule': lineparts[3]}
        alldata.append(thisset)
    # if there are not 4 parts and the data is perfect, this is an incorrect answer
    else:
        thisset["Incorrect"].append(lineparts[1])

print("Incorrect answers to first question:")
print(alldata[0]["Incorrect"])
```

So in the end, you get a list of dictionaries 'alldata'. Each dictionary corresponds to a problem. The incorrect answers are a themselves again a list of strings.